# Angular Material - Custom Autocomplete component

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I'm trying to create my own custom angular material component that would be able to work with a `mat-form-field` control.

Added to that, I'd like the control to use the `mat-autocomplete` directive.

My aim is simply to create a better-looking `mat-autocomplete` component with an integrated **clear-button** and custom **css arrow** like the following image. I have succesfully obtained it by using the standard component and added what I wanted but now I want to export it into a generic component.

[image: material component aim]

I'm using the official angular material documentation to create my own form field control and also another SO post about it which already helped me a lot :

- [Angular Material - Create custom form field control](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control)
- [Stack Overflow - custom component with ng value accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020051/angular-material-2-custom-component-with-ng-value-accessor)

I am currently facing several problems which I believe are linked :

- **My form is not valid even when the value is selected correctly.**
- **The placeholder is not setting itself correctly after an option is selected.**
- **The auto-complete filter option doesn't work at all**
- **The focus does not trigger correctly if I don't click on the input specifically.**

I believe my first three issues are caused by the auto-complete value that is not linked to my reactive form correctly.

---

Here is a direct link to a personnal public repository with the project (since the issue is a bit big to be displayed here) : [Git Repository : https://github.com/Tenmak/material](https://github.com/Tenmak/material).

---

Basically, the idea is to transform this :

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <div fxLayout="row">
      <input matInput placeholder="Thématique" [matAutocomplete]="thematicAutoComplete" formControlName="thematique" tabindex="1">

      <div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper">
        <div class="mat-select-arrow" [ngClass]="{'mat-select-arrow-down': !thematicAutoComplete.isOpen, 'mat-select-arrow-up': thematicAutoComplete.isOpen}"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button mat-button *ngIf="formDossier.get('thematique').value" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="formDossier.get('thematique').setValue('')">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <mat-hint class="material-hint-error" *ngIf="!formDossier.get('thematique').hasError('required') && formDossier.get('thematique').touched && formDossier.get('thematique').hasError('thematiqueNotFound')">
      <strong>
        Veuillez sélectionner un des choix parmi les options possibles.
      </strong>
    </mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-autocomplete #thematicAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayThematique">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let thematique of filteredThematiques | async" [value]="thematique">
      <span> {{thematique.code}} </span>
      <span> - </span>
      <span> {{thematique.libelle}} </span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

into this :

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <siga-auto-complete placeholder="Thématique" [tabIndex]="1" [autoCompleteControl]="thematicAutoComplete" formControlName="thematique">
    </siga-auto-complete>

    <mat-hint class="material-hint-error" *ngIf="!formDossier.get('thematique').hasError('required') && formDossier.get('thematique').touched && formDossier.get('thematique').hasError('thematiqueNotFound')">
      <strong>
        Veuillez sélectionner un des choix parmi les options possibles.
      </strong>
    </mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-autocomplete #thematicAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayThematique">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let thematique of filteredThematiques | async" [value]="thematique">
      <span> {{thematique.code}} </span>
      <span> - </span>
      <span> {{thematique.libelle}} </span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

I'm currently working in the "dossiers" folder which displays my initial reactive form. And I'm using my custom component `autocomplete.component.ts` inside this form directly to replace the first field.

Here is my attempt at the code of the generic component (**simplified**):

```
class AutoCompleteInput {
    constructor(public testValue: string) {
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'siga-auto-complete',
    templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./autocomplete.component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: MatFormFieldControl,
            useExisting: SigaAutoCompleteComponent
        },
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => SigaAutoCompleteComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ],
})
export class SigaAutoCompleteComponent implements MatFormFieldControl<AutoCompleteInput>, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor {
    ...
    parts: FormGroup;
    ngControl = null;

    ...

    @Input()
    get value(): AutoCompleteInput | null {
        const n = this.parts.value as AutoCompleteInput;
        if (n.testValue) {
            return new AutoCompleteInput(n.testValue);
        }
        return null;
    }
    set value(value: AutoCompleteInput | null) {
        // Should set the value in the form through this.writeValue() ??
        console.log(value);
        this.writeValue(value.testValue);
        this.stateChanges.next();
    }

    @Input()
    set formControlName(formName) {
        this._formControlName = formName;
    }
    private _formControlName: string;

    // ADDITIONNAL
    @Input() autoCompleteControl: MatAutocomplete;
    @Input() tabIndex: string;

    private subs: Subscription[] = [];

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private fm: FocusMonitor, private elRef: ElementRef) {
        this.subs.push(
            fm.monitor(elRef.nativeElement, true).subscribe((origin) => {
                this.focused = !!origin;
                this.stateChanges.next();
            })
        );

        this.parts = fb.group({
            'singleValue': '',
        });

        this.subs.push(this.parts.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
            this.propagateChange(value);
        }));
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // Wrong approach but some idea ?
        console.log(this.autoCompleteControl);
        this.autoCompleteControl.optionSelected.subscribe((event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) => {
            console.log(event.option.value);
            this.value = event.option.value;
        })
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.stateChanges.complete();
        this.subs.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
        this.fm.stopMonitoring(this.elRef.nativeElement);
    }

    ...

    // CONTROL VALUE ACCESSOR
    private propagateChange = (_: any) => { };

    public writeValue(a: string) {
        console.log('wtf');

        if (a && a !== '') {
            console.log('value => ', a);
            this.parts.setValue({
                'singleValue': a
            });
        }
    }
    public registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        return;
    }

    public setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Finally solved !!!

[image]

1. The problem here is when creating the input field in the child[SigaAutoCompleteComponent], the parent has to know about the
   value filled in the child [CreateDossierComponent], 
   that part is
   missing that is the reason it cant turn to valid as it thinks that
   input field is not touched [stays invalid] -- solved by emitting the
   value to parent then manipulating the form control as needed.
2. Spiltting up the mat-form-field and input caused the issue -- solved by moving mat-form-field element to child , other code stays intact
   and this solves both the placeholder overlapping and clicking on arrow icon to display
3. This can be done-[one way of doing by redesigning] , by injecting the service into child component and doing the autocomplete feature
   over there [i haven't implemented this, but this will work as it just copy of department field]

   in create-doiser.component.html

   ```
         <!-- </div> -->
         <mat-autocomplete #thematicAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayThematique">
           <mat-option *ngFor="let thematique of filteredThematiques | async" [value]="thematique">
             <span> {{thematique.code}} </span>
             <span> - </span>
             <span> {{thematique.libelle}} </span>
           </mat-option>
         </mat-autocomplete>
   ```

   > in autocomplete.component.html

   ```
   <mat-form-field style="display:block;transition:none ">
   <div fxLayout="row">
     <input  matInput   placeholder="Thématique" [matAutocomplete]="autoCompleteControl" (optionSelected)="test($event)" tabindex="{{tabIndex}}">
     <div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper" (click)="focus()">
       <div class="mat-select-arrow" [ngClass]="{'mat-select-arrow-down': !autoCompleteControl.isOpen, 'mat-select-arrow-up': autoCompleteControl.isOpen}"></div>
     </div>
   </div>

   </mat-form-field>
   ```

   > in autocomplete.component.ts

   ```
   in set value emit the value to parent
   this.em.emit(value);
   ```

   > create-dosier.component.ts

   ```
     this.thematique = new FormControl( ['', [Validators.required, this.thematiqueValidator]]

       ); 

   this.formDossier.addControl('thematique',this.thematique);
   call(event){

       this.thematique.setValue(event);
       this.thematique.validator=this.thematiqueValidator();
       this.thematique.markAsTouched();
       this.thematique.markAsDirty();

     }
   }
   ```

   this will resolve all the issues, Please let me know if you want me to push to github ..
   Hope this helps !!!! 
   Thanks !!

   **UPDATE:**
   Auto complete , mat-hint now everything is working..

   I understand that you don't want input and mat-form-field to be together

   > but if it is just for mat-hint to show dynamically[which is depending
   >   on 
   >         formcontrol values], we can pass the formcontrol from parent to child 
   >       which even eliminates the necessity of emitting the input value from 
   >         child to parent 
   >       setting the value in parent component and [mat-hint field stays in the parent component itself]

   [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'll look into it soon :)

Comment: Thanks to you as well :) , i have learned few things from this

Comment: Thanks for the insight with the emit part, I believe that was what was missing for the value to be passed down indeed. The problem I have with your solution, is that it's a really stuck-up custom component, and by that I mean I'd like this custom component not to be dependent of the `material-form-field` since it should interact with it from the outside. The aim is to be able to add dynamically material hints, and other HTML objects like that which are dependent on the `material-form-field`. For example, how do you manage the display of a `mat-hint` with this custom component ?

Comment: hi resolved that mat-hint as well...:) just we need to pass the formcontrol to child ..that would resolve the issue, as when you click on the value the form control changes..now i am not even emitting the values to set the value of input and still the mat-input works...as i said earlier just we need to move the mat-form-field to child !!! hope the updated solution works for you !!! :)

Comment: I'll look into it more but It is a bit far from what I originally wanted. I've been lacking time to really go into it in details, could you please do a PR on the git repo if possible ? I'd like to go in depth with this solution

Comment: Yes I understood that, you want to use only input in child and the other mat related items in parent..I am trying to do that one.. will push the changes to the git  asap thanks!!

Comment: hi tried to create branch under the git repo mentioned  ..unauthorized, forked it under https://github.com/HariDongli/material.git , this contains changes which is passing the formcontrol to child and covers all the scenarios you have mentioned. Thanks !!!

Comment: @AmpatiHareesh I have got the source from git . search is not working for the custom component. can you please add the git repo link for Reference. Thanks !!

Comment: @AmpatiHareesh . If possible can you please update this example with latest version of Angular